# Run Spring class asynchronously

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I'm working in an Spring application that downloads data from different APIs. For that purpose I need a class Fetcher that interacts with an API to fetch the needed data. One of the requirements of this class is that it has to have a method to start the fetching and a method to stop it. Also, it must download all asynchronously because users must be able to interact with a dashboard while fetching data.

Which is the best way to accomplish this? I've been reading about task executors and the different annotations of Spring to schedule tasks and execute them asynchronously but this solutions don't seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use the `Thread` class.  You supply a `Runnable` object that performs the fetching functionality in the `run()` method and when the Thread is started, it invokes the `run` method in a separate thread of execution.

So something like this:

```
public class Fetcher implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
      //do fetching stuff
    }
}

//in your code
Thread fetchThread = new Thread(new Fetcher());
fetchThread.start();
```

Now, if you want to be able to cancel, you can do that a couple of ways.  The easiest (albeit most violent and nonadvisable way to do it is to interrupt the thread:

```
fetchThread.interrupt();
```

The correct way to do it would be to implement logic in your `Fetcher` class that periodically checks a variable to see whether it should stop doing whatever it's doing or not.

**Edit** To your question about getting Spring to run it automatically, if you wanted it to run periodically, you'll need to use a scheduling framework like Quartz.  However, if you just want it to run once what you could do is use the `@PostConstruct` annotation.  The method annotated with `@PostConstruct` will be executed after the bean is created.  So you could do something like this

```
@Service
public class Fetcher implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
      //do stuff
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void goDoIt(){
      Thread trd = new Thread(this);
      trd.start();
    }
}
```

**Edit 2** I actually didn't know about this, but check out the `@Async` discussion in the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html) if you haven't already.  Might also be what you want to do.

Comment: Can I use @Autowired if I do that? Can I restrict to only one instance of the fetcher?

Comment: You can.  You would need to use the `@Singleton` or `@Service` annotation on the `Fetcher` class itself and then have that injected into whatever class is going to create the thread.  Does that make sense?

Comment: It does, partially. I'm going to use @Service to let Spring create an instance automatically. That means that I can't create a new instance by myself. Would be great if that instance created by Spring was executed in a different thread automatically.

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía you probably could get it to do that with some sort of executor framework or Quartz scheduler but that does add some complexity.  If you're new to threads, I would take it one step at a time and do it this way first before trying to get fancy with it.

Comment: I'm new with thread in Spring. That is the real problem :P I'm going to keep reading to try to figure out a way to do it. Thank you ^^

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía see my edits above for a dirty example of how you might do it

Answer (score 3):

Asynchronous task execution is what you're after and since Spring 3.0 you can achieve this using annotations too directly on the method you want to run asyncrhonously.

There are two ways of implementing this depending whether you are interested in getting a result from the async process:

```
@Async
public Future<ReturnPOJO> asyncTaskWithReturn(){
    //..
    return new AsyncResult<ReturnPOJO>(yourReturnPOJOInstance);
}
```

or not:

```
@Async
public void asyncTaskNoReturn() {
    //..
}
```

In the former method the result of your computation conveyed by yourReturnPOJOInstance object instance, is stored in an instance of `org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult<V>` which in return implements the `java.util.concurrent.Future<V>` that the caller can use to retrieve the result of the computation later on.

To activate the above functionality in Spring you have to add in your XML config file:

```
<task: annotation-driven />
```

along with the needed task namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You might only need certain methods to run on a separate thread rather than the entire class. If so, the `@Async` annotation is so simple and easy to use.

Simply add it to any method you want to run asynchronously, you can also use it on methods with return types thanks to Java's `Future` library.

**Check out this page:** http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async